How to check if origin server is available and able to complete Ajax requests using JavaScript
I'm wondering what would be the simplest method, using JavaScript, to check if the origin server is accessible and available to process Ajax requests? To provide more context: there are pages on this site, built in WordPress, that provide filterable lists of posts, and each interaction with a filter sends an Ajax request. The site is configured with an edge cache such that if the origin goes down, visitors would still access a cached version of the page. If, however, a visitor is viewing a cached page under these circumstances, the filters will not work, as Ajax requests to the origin will fail. Essentially, I would like a way to detect if a visitor is, in fact, viewing a static version of the page served by the edge cache and, if so, append a class to the <body> of the document.
I'm wondering if it would suffice to simply create an XMLHttpRequest instance and check its response in a manner such as the following, or is there a more reliable and/or efficient approach?
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// open request to primary site domain
xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com');

// check for response and apply class if origin is unavailable
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // can perform Ajax requests and origin is available
  } else {
    // cannot perform Ajax requests, thus origin must not be available
    document.body.classList.add("no-origin");
  }
};


Use xhr.onerror to detect an error connecting to the originl server.

@Barmar so with that approach, I would just remove the xhr.onload function and replace with xhr.onerror = function() { document.body.classList.add("no-origin"); } - is that correct?

Yes. But realize that this will likely be detected by a timeout, which could take 10 seconds or more.

Hm, good point- would there be a faster approach for checking what I've described above (i.e. if one is viewing a page on the edge cache), or is this the only way?

Check the documentation of the caching service, find out if they provide a way to annotate the cached documents to distinguish them from origin documents.

You really only use the caching service as a backup when the origin is down? Many sites use a caching service for all the static files, even if they make dynamic calls to the origin, just to reduce load on the origin.

That's a good question- I believe the service is Fastly, so I will check their docs.

Checking for the accessibility of a small server resource:
<img src="https://someserver.com/tiny.jpg" onload="Plan_A();" onerror="this.onerror=null; Plan_B();" style="display:none;">


Here's all you need to check for accessibility...
try{

 let Url = new URL('https://example.com');

 // all is good so proceed processing right here

} catch(e){    

 // The site is not accessible, continue with plan B

}


This checks the syntactic validity of the URL, not the availability
